# Tmux and dim-ed colours in Terminal.app on MacOS

Tags: terminal, osx, tmux, colors, macintosh

## The problem

On my Mac (10.11) *Tmux* does not show `dim`-ed colours properly, and this causes annoyance.

In the following picture, the commit author's name is supposed to be represented in `dim white`. This works fine in the *Terminal.app* but not within *Tmux*.

[image: git lg1 comparison]

Does anyone have any clue about how to debug this?
I believe it is related to the `$TERM` variable, but I wouldn't know where to start.

In *Terminal.app* `$TERM` is set to `xterm-256color`.
In *Tmux* `$TERM` is set to `screen-256color`.

In my `.tmux.conf` I have `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`.  `xterm-256color`, within *Tmux*, conflicts with *Vim*'s background colour, somehow, but doesn't change the `dim` behaviour.

### More information

I've open an [issue on *Tmux*'s GitHub repository](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/135); an answer has been provided, but I do not entirely understand it.

It looks like *Terminal.app* does not have a `dim` directive, although it deals just fine with it.
*Tmux* cannot fetch the `dim` information, since it is absent, and therefore it does not show the font properly.

Now I am not sure why one works whereas the other does not.

Comment: Try `echo $TERM` both in and out of tmux, and add the output to the question. Off the top of my head, I would guess that the value in the underlying terminal needs to have `-256color` added; `tmux` picks up on this.

Comment: @TomHunt, did it. Nor `screen-256color` or `xterm-256color` works well with the `dim` directive... :(

Comment: Did you set that within tmux, or in the underlying terminal? tmux looks at the terminal it's started in. Try detaching, then running `TERM=xterm-256color tmux att`, or so.

Comment: `$TERM` is already set to `xterm-256color` in *Terminal.app*. Therefore calling `TERM=xterm-256color tmux` did not have any effect. I did set them in *Tmux* configuration file as `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"` and `"xterm-256color"`.

Comment: This is what finally pushed me to use iTerm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Easy fix

Add the following code to `~/.tmux.conf`.

```
set -sa terminal-overrides ",*:dim=\\E[2m"
```

## Explanation tentative

*Application.app* seems to do not have the `dim` directive (see number 24).

```
Terminal 0: xterm-256color [references=1, flags=0x1]:
   1: acsc: (string) ``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~
   0: AX: (flag) true
   2: bel: (string) \007
...
  23: dch1: (string) \033[P
  24: dim: [missing]
  25: dl: (string) \033[%p1%dM
```

This is the output of the command `tmux showmsgs -T` run inside *Tmux*.

On the other side, *Terminal.app* "sends" the `dim` anyway (no idea of **how** or **why**), since it is working, as shown in the picture above.

Adding the missing `dim` directive (**magically**) solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`tmux` (like GNU screen) works by translating the features of your actual terminal into an (often different) internal terminal.  They do this to allow you to connect a session on different terminals *at the same time*, or *at different times*.

When that works well, you will see the "same" text no matter where you are connecting from.

Not all terminals support **`dim`**.  As matter of fact, most do not.  The terminal database has 121 occurrences of **`dim`** versus 1514 terminal descriptions.

When `screen` was begun around 1990, its developers chose to ignore that feature and instead supply the most useful.  They designed the program to store, for each row/column cell, the video attributes that ***termcap*** programs were likely to use.  The source-code defines these:

```
#define ATTR_DI         0       /* Dim mode */
#define ATTR_US         1       /* Underscore mode */
#define ATTR_BD         2       /* Bold mode */
#define ATTR_RV         3       /* Reverse mode */
#define ATTR_SO         4       /* Standout mode */
#define ATTR_BL         5       /* Blinking */
```

but both `screen` and `tmux` use these *internal* features only if the *external* terminal supports them, as well as being provided in the *internal* terminal description.

OSX bundles a copy of [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html) and the [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html#download_database).  While you could install MacPorts or homebrew and get a *later* version, what OSX *has* is **`ncurses 5.7.20081102`**.  If you use `infocmp` to show the terminal descriptions you would see something like this:

```
$ infocmp screen-256color
#       Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /usr/share/terminfo/73/screen-256color
screen-256color|GNU Screen with 256 colors,
        am, km, mir, msgr, xenl,
        colors#256, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, ncv#3, pairs#32767,
        acsc=++\,\,--..00``aaffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
        bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, cbt=\E[Z, civis=\E[?25l,
        clear=\E[H\E[J, cnorm=\E[34h\E[?25h, cr=^M,
        csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=^H,
        cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=^J, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
        cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\EM,
        cvvis=\E[34l, dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dl=\E[%p1%dM,
        dl1=\E[M, ed=\E[J, el=\E[K, el1=\E[1K, enacs=\E(B\E)0,
        flash=\Eg, home=\E[H, ht=^I, hts=\EH, ich=\E[%p1%d@,
        il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[L, ind=^J, initc@, is2=\E)0, kbs=^H,
        kcbt=\E[Z, kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA,
        kdch1=\E[3~, kend=\E[4~, kf1=\EOP, kf10=\E[21~,
        kf11=\E[23~, kf12=\E[24~, kf2=\EOQ, kf3=\EOR, kf4=\EOS,
        kf5=\E[15~, kf6=\E[17~, kf7=\E[18~, kf8=\E[19~, kf9=\E[20~,
        khome=\E[1~, kich1=\E[2~, kmous=\E[M, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~,
        nel=\EE, op=\E[39;49m, rc=\E8, rev=\E[7m, ri=\EM, rmacs=^O,
        rmcup=\E[?1049l, rmir=\E[4l, rmkx=\E[?1l\E>, rmso=\E[23m,
        rmul=\E[24m, rs2=\Ec\E[?1000l\E[?25h, sc=\E7,
        setab=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;%p1%d%;m,
        setaf=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m,
        sgr=\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p1%t;3%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p3%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;m%?%p9%t\016%e\017%;,
        sgr0=\E[m\017, smacs=^N, smcup=\E[?1049h, smir=\E[4h,
        smkx=\E[?1h\E=, smso=\E[3m, smul=\E[4m, tbc=\E[3g,
```

There is no **`dim`** there.  In ncurses, this was added in [April 2015](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20150422):

```
# 2015-04-22
#       + add 'dim' capability to screen entry (report by Leonardo B Schenkel)
#       + add several key definitions to nsterm-bce to match preconfigured
#         keys, e.g., with OSX 10.9 and 10.10 (report by Leonardo B Schenkel)
```

Likewise, you would not see **`dim`** in xterm-256color.  That was added in [June 2014](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#t20140614):

```
# 2014-06-14
#       + modify sgr for screen.xterm-new to support dim capability -TD
#       + add dim capability to nsterm+7 -TD
#       + cancel dim capability for iterm -TD
#       + add dim, invis capabilities to vte-2012 -TD
#       + add sitm/ritm to konsole-base and mlterm3 -TD
```

The manner in which **`dim`** is used in the external Terminal.app is not indicated, but likely hardcoded (not using the terminal description).  But `screen` and `tmux` do not know *how* the escape sequences come in, but know that **`dim`** is not mentioned in the terminal description, hence not supported.

You can update your terminfo database to add the `dim` feature to these terminal descriptions, using the `infocmp` and `tic` utilities:

- use `infocmp` to get the existing terminal descriptions for `xterm-256color` and `screen-256color`.  This shows just the first; you would of course repeat the process for the second description:

  infocmp -1x xterm-256color > foo
- edit the text file created by `infocmp`, adding this line

  ```
  dim=\E[2m,
  ```

  and replacing the line with `sgr=` with this line:

  ```
  sgr=%?%p9%t\E(0%e\E(B%;\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p5%t;2%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p7%t;8%;m,
  ```
- use `tic` to replace the terminal description:

  sudo tic -x foo

***Note:*** The point of the question was asking *why* this happens; Nicholas Marriott provided the information for *how* to work around the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. Although you provided references, I still do not really understand what *ncurses* and *terminal database* are. I tried to read up, but the explanation it's beyond my background knowledge. P.S. I do have *homebrew* on my system, and I would love to experiment anything you may suggest.

Comment: Is there a fix involving a brew install?

Comment: It looks as if both MacPorts and homebrew have ncurses 6.1, which includes the changes mentioned above.

Comment: `sudo tic -x foo` in the above makes no difference on macOS due to system protection features (SIP). Simply make sure you are running the macOS provided tic by doing: `/usr/bin/tic -x foo`. It will install to `~/.terminfo`.